# Setting Value of an Input Tag in WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I am attempting to help a user log into their account using a custom `WebBrowser` control. I am trying to set the value of an input tag to the players username using the `WebBrowser`'s `InvokeScript` function. However, my current solution is doing nothing but rendering a blank white page.

My current code looks like this (web is the name for my `WebBrowser` control):

```
web.Navigate(CurrentURL, null, @"<script type='text/javascript'>
    function SetPlayerData(input) {
        username.value = input;
        return true;
    }
</script>");
web.Navigated += (o, e) =>
{
    web.IsScriptEnabled = true;
    web.InvokeScript("SetPlayerData", @"test");
};
```

As mentioned, this does not work right now. I am attempting to do this on Windows Phone so a number of the example's I have found here and in other places will not work as I do not have access to the same functions.

How would I perform this successfully?

EDIT: Perhaps I was not clear, but I am working with Windows Phone, which has a limited API available meaning I do not have access to the `Document` property and a number of other functions. I do have access to `InvokeScript`, but not much more.

Answer (score 14):

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("navbar_username").InnerText ="Tester";
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("navbar_password").InnerText = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

foreach (HtmlElement HtmlElement1 in webBrowser1.Document.Body.All)
    {
    if (HtmlElement1.GetAttribute("value") == "Log in")
        {
        HtmlElement1.InvokeMember("click");
        break;
        }
    }
```

you may find more here : http://deltahacker.gr/2011/08/15/ftiakste-to-diko-sas-robot/

Comment: The Windows Phone WebBrowser control does not have a Document property.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's been along time since this question is posted but I think I'll post an answer to this so that it will help some one who came across the same situation

```
try
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("navbar_username").SetAttribute("value", "your user");
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("navbar_password").SetAttribute("value", "your pass");
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Log in").InvokeMember("click");
        }
        catch { }
```